# Как реализовать класс

Tags: java, ооп

У меня есть класс Pellets, он из себя представляет координаты точек попадания в мишень и прочую вспомогательную информацию.

В программе я создаю `ArrayList<Pellets>` и в него добавляют точки попаданий, но есть одна проблема - центр мишени.

В программе я задаю центр мишени, это соответственно тот же объект Pellets, и к этому центру идут свои точки попадания. Т.е. создается условно говоря массив Pellets у которого первый элемент это центр мишени, а все остальные это уже попадания, но это как-то не красиво.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать в Java, чтобы можно было обращаться к этой группой таким образом:

```
Target.getCenter.getX <- выдает Х координату центра, 
Target.GetPellets(i).getX <- выдает Х координату попадания.
```

---

```
public class Pellets {

    private int x, y, scale, size;
    private Color color;
    private int halfSize;

    Pellets(int xPellets, int yPellets, int scalePellets, int sizePellets, Color cPellets){
        x = xPellets;
        y = yPellets;
        scale = scalePellets;
        size = sizePellets;
        color = cPellets;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public int getScale(){
        return scale;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public Color getColor(){
        return color;
    }

    public int getHalfSize() {
        halfSize = size / 2;
        return halfSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте класс `Target`:

```
public class Target {
    private Pellets mCenter;
    private ArrayList<Pellets> mPellets;

    public Target(Pellets pellets) {
        mCenter = pellets;
        mPellets = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addPellet(Pellets pellets) {
        mPellets.add(pellets);
    }

    public Pellets getPellet(int i) {
        return mPellets.get(i);
    }

    public Pellets getCenter() {
        return mCenter;
    }
}
```

Далее можно создать объект класса `Target`:

```
Pellets center = new Pellets(...);
Target target = new Target(center);
```

и добавлять в `target` новые точки попаданий:

```
Pellets pellets = new Pellets(...);
target.addPellet(pellets);
```

или получать их и их атрибуты:

```
int x = target.getPellet(1).getX();
```

Также рекомендую в классе `Target` реализовать проверку, например, в методе `getPellet(...)` на наличие элемента с переданным индексом и тому подобные.